# net.request post data not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Posting data using net.request is not working. It's reaching the URL. But data not posted. My code is below. Please help me on this.

```
const net = remote.net;
const querystring = require('querystring');

//**
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'username' : 'test',
    'password': 'test'
});

const request = net.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1/post.php',
});

request.on('error', (error) => {});

request.on('response', (response) => {});


request.write(postData);
request.end();
```

Comment: I may be wrong here, but do you really mean `remote.net`? If so, where is it defined since it doesn't appear to be defined in the Electron API docs?

Comment: Yes, const remote = require('electron').remote or const net = require('electron').remote.net;

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while. But for the next people who will have the same problem.

Don't forget you must be declare the size of your "postData" in the header.
for example :

```js
var postData = JSON.stringify({"q" : sqlQuery });
const request = net.request({
        method: 'POST',
        protocol: 'http:',
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/select',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': postData.length
        }
       }) 
request.on('response', (response) => {
.... // Something
})
request.write(postData)
request.end()
```

Comment: I didn't need `length`, but `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` worked for me.

Comment: headers don't exist in type `ClientRequestConstructorOptions`, should use `request.setHeader()`

Answer (score 1):

When using `net.request` you need to call `request.end()` after you write your data to assure the request data has been sent.

The reason you need to call `request.end()` is to allow for changes to be made to the headers and body of your request before you actually make it.

`request()` will connect and wait for `request.end()` to send the headers and body in one pass.

Also, it is never a good idea to ignore responses if you want to understand what your code is doing.

You really should hook the `request.response` event to see what, if any, errors occurred, as in:

```
request.on('response', (response) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
})
```

#### Updated - per comment

Your code should read (expanded from example code for [net](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/net/) in Electron API Docs):

```
const request = net.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1/post.php',
})

let body = ''

request.on('response', (response) => {

  // check response.statusCode to determine if the request succeeded
  console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)

  // capture body of response 
  // - can be called more than once for large result
  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
    body += chunk.toString()
  })

  // when response is complete, print body
  response.on('end', () => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${body}`)
  })
})

request.write(postData)

request.end()
```

Comment: yes, create the request, hook the `response` event, write data, and then call `request.end()`

Comment: It seems not working. I have create a log for the data in post.php. it's not receiving the postData

Comment: Please update your question with your refactored code.

Comment: That's not working for me. The request sends when net.request is called and nothing happens when request.write(postData) is called. Is that a electron version issue. my electron version is  1.4

Comment: @Jay I could not get this to work either and am seeing same issue as Jay